# Condition of the eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

**[Ciarlet, 2.3-1]** I know this result:

> Let $A$ a diagonalisable matrix, $P$ a matrix such that
>   $$P^{-1}AP\ =\ \mbox{diag}(\lambda_i)\ =\ D,$$
>   and $\|\cdot\|$ a matrix norm satisfying
>   $$\|\mbox{diag}(d_i)\|\ =\ \max_i|d_i|$$
>   for every diagonal matrix. Then, for every matrix $\delta A$,
>   $$\mbox{sp}(A+\delta A)\ =\ \{\mu : (A+\delta A)x=\mu x, \mbox{ for some } x\in\mathbb{C}^n\}\ \subset\ \bigcup_{i=1}^ND_i,$$
>   where
>   $$D_i\ =\ \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-\lambda_i|\leq\mbox{cond}(P)\|\delta A\|\}.$$

Now, I want to prove that: If there exists an integer $m$ satisfying $1\leq m\leq n$ such that the union $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^mD_i$ of the $m$ disk $D_i$ is disjoint form the union $\bigcup\limits_{i=m+1}^nD_i$ of the remaining $n-m$ disks (it is always possible to assum that it is the first $m$ and last $n-m$ disks which have this property), then the union $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^mD_i$ contains exactly $m$ eigenvalues of the matrix $A + \delta A$.

---

Please, somebody have an idea to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to use the diagonalized form of $A$? Recall that $B$ and $P^{-1}BP$ have the same spectrum.

Comment: So, you say that I need to use the fact of $A$ and $P^{-1}AP$ have the same spectrum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $\hat{A}(\alpha) = A+\alpha\delta A$ and note that $\mathrm{sp}(\hat{A}(\alpha))\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^N D_i$ for $\alpha\in[0,1]$.
Recall that the eigenvalues of a matrix depend continuously on the coefficients of said matrix.
Therefore, we have continuous paths $\lambda_i\colon[0,1]\to\bigcup_{j=1}^N D_j$ such that $\mathrm{sp}(\hat{A}(\alpha)) = \{\lambda_i(\alpha)|i\in\{1,\ldots,N\}\}$.
Without loss of generality we may label the $\lambda_i$ such that $\lambda_i(0)\in D_i$.

Since $\bigcup_{i=1}^m D_i$ is disjoint from $\bigcup_{i=m+1}^N D_i$ and since both are closed, no path can start in the former and end in the latter. For $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$, $\lambda_i$ is a path starting in the former and hence ending in the former as well.

Topological intermezzo:
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are closed sets and suppose that $p\colon[0,1]\to A\cup B$ is a continuous path such that $p(0)\in A$ and $p(1)\in B$.
By continuity of $p$, $p^{-1}(A)\subseteq [0,1]$ is closed as well as $p^{-1}(B)\subseteq [0,1]$.
Furthermore, $[0,1] = p^{-1}(A\cup B) = p^{-1}(A)\cup p^{-1}(B)$, thus since both are closed $\inf(p^{-1}(B))\in p^{-1}(A)\cap p^{-1}(B)$.
It follows that $p(\inf(p^{-1}(B)))\in A\cap B$ hence $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint.

By contraposition, if $A$ and $B$ are closed and disjoint, no continuous path $p$ can exists such that $p(0)\in A$ and $p(1)\in B$.

Thus, we conclude $\lambda_1(1),\ldots,\lambda_m(1)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^m D_i$, where $\lambda_1(1),\ldots,\lambda_m(1)\in\mathrm{sp}(A+\delta A)$.

By the same argument $\lambda_{m+1}(1),\ldots,\lambda_{N}(1)\in\bigcup_{i=m+1}^N D_i$, where $\lambda_{m+1}(1),\ldots,\lambda_N(1)\in\mathrm{sp}(A+\delta A)$ proving your conjecture.

Comment: The first paragraph is evident for the result in the gray box. But, if $\lambda$, eigenvalue of $A + \delta A$, is in $D_i$, then $\lambda\in\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m D_i\; \underline{\vee}\ \lambda\in\bigcup\limits_{i=m+1}^N D_i$, but that doesn't guarantee that exists exactly $m$ eigenvalues of $A + \delta A$ in $\lambda\in\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m D_i$. Can you please justify more your answer?

Comment: But $\lambda_1(0),\ldots,\lambda_m(0)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^m D_i$, right? Thus by connectedness $\lambda_1(1),\ldots,\lambda_m(1)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^m D_i$ as well.

Comment: I've rewritten the last paragraph. Maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: That's right, $\lambda_1(0),\ldots,\lambda_m(0)\in\bigcup_{i=1}^m D_i$, but $\lambda_1(1)$ isn't necessarily "connected" with $\lambda_1(0)$. You need to proved that first. The only thing that you know is, there exists $1\leq i_0\leq N$, such that $\lambda_1(1)\in D_{i_0}$, but $i_0 > m$ or $i_0 \leq m$? I only know that $$|\lambda_1(1) - \lambda_{i_0}(0)| = \min_i|\lambda_1(1) - \lambda_{i}(0)|.$$

Comment: You **do** know $\lambda_i(0)$ and $\lambda_i(1)$ are connected, since $\lambda_i$ is a path between them lying completely in $\bigcup_{i=1}^N D_i$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the second paragraph isn't clear for me. Can you please show more detail? Thanks again

Comment: What's your background in topology? Do you know that paths cannot leave a connected component?

Comment: My background in topology is poor. I am in a Numerical Linear Algebra Course, so paths? I don't get it. I understood that "eigenvalues of a matrix depend continuously on the coefficients of said matrix", then $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta > 0\; /\; |t_1 - t_2| < \delta \Rightarrow |\lambda_i(t_1) - \lambda_i(t_2)| <\varepsilon,$$ and I suppose that you set $\varepsilon = \mbox{cond}(P)\|\delta A\|$, but later I can not follow you. Thanks

Comment: I've added a 'Topological intermezzo'. Is it clearer now? I'm afraid the result is intrinsically very topological, so I really can't help but using some topology.

Comment: Thank you and don't worry about the topology, Now I follow you, before I couldn't understand why $\lambda_i(1)\in\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^m$, but now is clear, thanks so much.

Comment: Yeah, now is clear for me, too! Very well Abel.

Comment: Last question. Why $\inf(p^{-1}(B))\in p^{-1}(A)\cap p^{-1}(B)$? Thanks

Comment: And, where do you use that $p(0)\in A$ and $p(1)\in B$?

Comment: @ShanaKugimiya To your first question: Since $p^{-1}(B)$ is closed it contains its infimum and since $p^{-1}(A)\cup p^{-1}(B) = [0,1]$, $p^{-1}(B)^c\subseteq p^{-1}(A)$ and thus by closedness of $p^{-1}(A)$, $\inf(p^{-1}(B))\in p^{-1}(A)$ as well. To your second question: I use $p(0)\in A$ and $p(1)\in B$ somewhat implicitly to have $p^{-1}(A)\neq\varnothing$ and $p^{-1}(B)\neq\varnothing$.